# C program to display largest and smallest number from 3 number which is taken input from user

Tags: c, logic

I need to solve this problem:

I have 3 nubmers **A,B,C** and i need to find the minimum and the maximum in the same if statemeant.

I writed the code below and it didn't works, i need to solve that problem **in this format** could anyone help me?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a,b,c;
   printf("\nEnter Three numbers = ");
   scanf("%d%d%d",&a ,&b, &c);
   if( (a > b) && (a > c) )
   {
        if(b > c)
        {
             printf("a is largest\n");
             printf("c is smallest\n");

        }
        else
        {
             printf("a is largest\n");
             printf("b is smallest\n");
        }
   }
   else
   {
        if(c > a)
        {
             printf("c is largest\n");
             printf("b is smallest\n");
        }
        else
        {
             printf("a is largest\n");
             printf("c is smallest\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

---

Need it kind of like this in single if statement. Please help me out

Comment: Please edit this post to fix the code format.  Just indent 4 spaces to cause it to use the code font.  Most people won't waste their time trying to read this mess as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
A | B | C
----------
2 | 1 | 0 
2 | 0 | 1
1 | 2 | 0 
1 | 0 | 2
0 | 1 | 2
0 | 2 | 1
```

SO-
if A is the big so B or C is the smallest so your condition is OK
else C\B is the biggest and the smallet is the small between the second and A .

```
if((a>b)&&(a>c){
   if(b>c){ printf("A biggest , C smallest);
     }else{ printf("A biggest , B smallest);
}else{
   if(b>c){
     if(a>c){ printf("B biggest , C smallest);
       }else{ printf("B biggest , A smallest);
   }else{
     if(a>b){ printf("C biggest , B smallest);
       }else{ printf("C biggest , A smallest);
     }
   }
}
```

I hope that will help you. i didn't check if the code compile but i think its **work**